# bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' exception: QueryDSL MongoDb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, querydsl

In our project, we are implementing dynamic query with the help of QueryDSL MongoDB. Our application is using MongoDB as a database. we are getting this error. We can able to create generate Q class and also able to write the query using Predicate. But while running the application getting above error response as `Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception`. When searched most of them recommend the jar conflicts. 
Exception stack trace as below

```
ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@78a773fd: startup date [Wed Jan 16 18:46:36 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.attinad</groupId>

 <description>A project for content management system APIs</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
   <version>1.11.106</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <!--<scope>provided</scope> -->
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring Security -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

  

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
     <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
   <version>3.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Mongo -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- SWAGGER -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.1</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.1</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.17</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        
  

 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
     <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
       <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
       <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
      </path>
     </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   
    <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>
                                org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor
                            </processor>
                            <logOnlyOnError>true</logOnlyOnError>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>

 <artifactId>content-management-system</artifactId>
 <name>content-management-system</name>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved above issue by removing dependency spring data commons core and removed the version of spring data commons. Found the problem is due to jar mismatch of different jar versions. If any such problem exists, check for jar file conflict for dependency, if no solution worked then create a new project with required dependency replace that dependency.